# Form de menu DropDown Não aparece ao clicar botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Estou fazendo um menu com **DropDown** utilizando `bootstrap`. Que ao clicar no botão entrar ele exibe os campos para o usuário colocar o email e senha. Porém ao clicar o botão o formulário não é exibido. Segue uma imagem e o código **HTML e JS** para explicar melhor o que preciso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Handles menu drop down
    $('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Resenha Informal</title>

    <script rel="script" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap-3.3.7/bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap-3.3.7/bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.js">
    <script rel="script" src="Scripts/Site.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Site.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Sign In</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu form-login stop-propagation" role="menu">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" /></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" /></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como resolvo este problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Renan,

Para atingir o seu objetivo utilizando o [Bootstrap Dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns), não é necessário nenhum `JavaScript` adicional.

Modifiquei seu código me baseando nos templates disponibilizado pelo site do bootstrap. E está do jeito que você sugeriu na imagem.

Basta dar continuidade em sua lógica.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Resenha Informal</title>

  <script rel="script" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static" id="navbar-example">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="collapsed navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-example-js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Meu projeto</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-example-js-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop3" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Registro </a> 
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
                <li style="padding: 15px;">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Submit</button>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop3" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Entrar <span class="caret"></span> </a> 
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
                  <li><a href="#">Outras ações...</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado, um abraço.